# Web Application as Proxy Web-server in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy, web-applications

can i write a web-App in Tomcat and set it in deployment to act as a proxy WebApp, meaning it will receive the request from some web browser for intermediate processing and further forwarding?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without claiming that this is the definitive answer: I assume it is not possible.

Usually, you map a path prefix to a web application.

I.e. http://your.site/app will map to a single application.

The web server (tomcat resp. frontent server) will see a GET (e.g.) request for /app (without the host part).

The request line looks like this:

> GET /app HTTP/1.1

With a proxy, things are different. The whole URL is submitted to the proxy server and a request line would look like:

> GET http://your.site/app HTTP/1.1

I would assume there is not way to handle that with Tomcat, as it is simply not made for that.

There might be an option to use a frontend proxy (apache) and to rewrite URLs before passing them to the app, but that sounds rather odd.

Comment: just to add: Maybe you may want to describe your scenario which you are trying to solve. Squid for example can be configured in many ways and might solve your problem if it is about access control, URL redirection etc.

Comment: the scenario would involve a proxy written from me, which get the request of the client before "forwarding it" to the target Host or URL. i think Squid fall a little bit short of the requirement